# Assigning a double to a struct

Tags: c++

I stumbled upon something the other day in the code of a colleague and I want to understand how/why this works.

He uses a struct like this

```
 struct my_struct
 {

   my_struct(){ /* default constructor*/};
   my_struct(char c){ /*some special constructor*/};
   // other stuff
   my_struct& operator=(const my_struct &ms){ /* assignment */};
  };
```

Originally through a typo he figured out that the following works

```
  my_struct ms;
  double a;
  ms = a;
```

I have worked out that this is equal (in the sense of gives the same final struct ms) to the following

```
  my_struct ms;
  double a;
  my_struct ms2((char) a);
  ms=ms2;
```

But I don't know why. Personally, I think this should not work, because there is no assign operator for double and my_struct and additionally because there is no constructor for my_struct using a double.

I tried to google this, but did not find anything relevant.

@ user657267: i wanted to keep it as short as possible, you could add a line a=5; or whatever the same would apply.

Comment: `ms = a;` is undefined behavior, `a` hasn't been initialized.

Comment: there is an implicit conversion from double to char

Comment: FWIW, if you make the constructor from `char` `explicit`, then GCC silently accepts `my_struct ms(a);` but warns for `my_struct ms{a};` (per -Wnarrowing)....  Strangely, this is a bit weaker than the behaviour of assignment to struct members where there's no constructor, as the Standard mandates an error for `T var{ ... }` causing narrowing conversions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

During the compilation this:

```
ms = a;
```

attempts to resolve an assignment of one or more of the following immediate forms

```
my_struct& operator ()(double)
my_struct& operator ()(double&)
my_struct& operator ()(const double&)
```

and a litany of other potential conversion from `double`. And none is found. In fact, only the following is discovered:

```
my_struct& operator=(const my_struct &ms)
```

which indicates the compiler does allow assignment via a const-reference of another `my_struct`. At that time a *conversion constructor* is sought, starting with the most immediate conversion (explicit to the type `double`:

```
my_struct(double)
my_struct(double&)
my_struct(const double&)
```

It is important to note such a constructor *cannot* mandate *explicit* use. We're implicitly constructing a temporary, and as such explicit mandate is off the reservation.

Anyway, again, none is found. Before giving up the compiler attempts to locate a constructor of *any* form that can convert from `double` to whatever the fundamental construction requires *and* said constructor supports implicit construction. In effect, something of the form

```
my_struct(<<something that can be converted from a double>>)
```

And again, the constructor cannot be `explicit`. As it turns out, this search *does* find this:

```
my_struct(char)
```

because `double` can be converted to `char` (albeit poorly and likely not what you want). The entire chain is a little (ok, a *lot*) more complicated than that, but that is the crux of it.

You can avoid this implicit construction by ensuring that constructor is only `explicit` in usage, but that is a double-edge sword, so care is required. Use of `explicit` can be somewhat harsh. Doing this:

```
explicit my_struct(char)
```

will squelch the unintended implicit construction when converting `double` to `char`. But I warn you; it will also squelch the ability to do this:

```
char x = 'a';
my_struct ms;
ms = x;
```

because now `my_struct` cannot be *implicitly* constructed *at all* from `char`, by conversion or otherwise. There are multiple ways around this, including defining a specific assignment operator for the type (takes a `double`) or a specific conversion constructor (takes a `double`). How you approach that I leave to you.

Answer (score 3):

You have yourself a conversion constructor:

```
my_struct(char c)
```

This means anything that can be converted to `char` can be used to implicitly create an object of `my_struct`.

In order to avoid this you can add `explicit` to your constructor:

```
explicit my_struct(char c)
```

This way you can create an object from double like this:

```
double a = my_initial_value;
my_struct ms2(a);
```

Also, always initialize your variables, otherwise types like `int`, `float`, pointers etc. will hold random values.

Comment: "anything that can be converted to `char` can be used" - no, only types that can be converted with a standard conversion (i.e. built-in numeric types). User-defined types can't be used, since a conversion sequence can't contain more than one user-defined conversion.

Comment: @MikeSeymour that comment is important and I probably should have specified it in my answer, but didn't bother as there was only one UDT in the chain. It is definitely important to note.